# IObservable .Cast<>() and covariance

Tags: c#, system.reactive, covariance

I have two different event types implementing the same interface:

```
interface InputEvent { }

struct KeyboardEvent : InputEvent { }
struct MouseEvent : InputEvent { }
```

I have two streams, one of each event type:

```
IObservable<KeyboardEvent> KeyboardStream;
IObservable<MouseEvent> MouseStream;
```

I would like to introduce a merged `IObservable<InputEvent>` stream of both. At first I hoped that the compiler would automatically detect the base class:

```
IObservable<InputEvent> Merged = Observable.Merge(KeyboardStream, MouseStream);
```

No luck there, so I tried being explicit:

```
IObservable<InputEvent> Merged = Observable.Merge<InputEvent>(KeyboardStream, MouseStream);
```

Nope, compiler still doesn't get the hint. So I cast each explicitly:

```
IObservable<InputEvent> Merged = Observable.Merge<InputEvent>((IObservable<InputEvent>)KeyboardStream, (IObservable<InputEvent>)MouseStream);
```

Yuck. And it still fails at runtime with a cast fail. I guess this is something to do with covariance (I still don't *fully* get that on the first try...) so I'll do what I would do with IEnumerable, use `.Cast<T>()`:

```
IObservable<InputEvent> Merged = Observable.Merge<InputEvent>(KeyboardStream.Cast<InputEvent>(), MouseStream.Cast<InputEvent>());
```

Now the compiler tells me that `.Cast<T>()` is only defined for `IObservable<Object>`... **What?** That seems like a pretty inconvenient and unnecessary restraint.

Finally I try a simple select:

```
IObservable<InputEvent> Merged = Observable.Merge(KeyboardStream.Select(i => (InputEvent)i), MouseStream.Select(i => (InputEvent)i));
```

Success at last! It works and I can create my own simple extension method from it. However, the built-in `.Cast<T>()` and `.OfType<T>()` operators leave a pretty bad taste in my mouth. So my question is: **why can't I use the built-in `.Cast<T>()` extension on any observable other than `Object`** which is pretty much redundant? Is it a covariance issue? An oversight in the Rx spec? A deliberate design decision?

Comment: What version of C# are you using, and what version of .NET? `Cast` only takes `IObservable<object>`, but that should be fine - because `IObservable<T>` is covariant in `T`. Can you produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? That would make it easier to help.

Comment: I am an idiot. My types are **structs** - I just spent half an hour typing up a post that doesn't even make sense. At least I got a response from Jon Skeet though!

Comment: Gah - I even looked for that, but completely missed it. Still, at least that explains everything :)

Comment: Great post/question.  +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that my event types were `struct`s and therefore weren't automatically boxed to Object. Changing the types to `class` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As a warning even though this appears to be solved, IObservable / IObserver isn't covariant on all platforms - specifically, WP7 and Silverlight decided to strip the covariance from the interface declaration.